# gl.begin() after gl.end() -> rendering is black

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm trying to render different primities in the same context. When I Do

```
        OpenGL gl = GlControl.OpenGL;
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | openGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINES);

        gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.Vertex(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.End();
```

Everything is fine. But when I do

```
        OpenGL gl = GlControl.OpenGL;            
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | openGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINES);

        gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.Vertex(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.End();

        gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_POINT);
        gl.Color(1.0f, 0, 0);
        gl.Vertex(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);        
        gl.End();
```

I don't see anything anymore...

Comment: Try adding glPointSize(10.0f); before the second glBegin(). Can you see the dot?

Answer (score 4):

The valid tokens for immediate mode `glBegin` (which you should not use BTW) does not contain `GL_POINT`. You probably meant `GL_POINTS`. Using an invalid token causes an OpenGL error which may trip your particular C# bindings.

Answer (score 3):

`GL_POINT` is not allowed as argument to `gl.Begin` and should through a `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. If you want to draw points, the correct code would be

```
 gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_POINTS);
                         ^
```

You should definitely check the return value of glGetError().